# How do you specify a link to a blind combinatorialist?

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, graph-theory, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Regular projections of links look like graphs in the plane.  So I'm wondering if it would be possible to specify a link up to isotopy with purely combinatorial data about this graph.  If so, what kind of dictionary is there between graphs of valency 4 and isotopy classes of links?  Of course it has to be a one-way dictionary (from graphs to links) since links have many different regular projections.  I suppose this may also just be a question about how you know when a graph of valency 4 imbeds in the plane, a question which I assume has some general formulation which has been thoroughly studied. But that would still leave the question of whether isomorphic graphs (with the same "over-under" data for crossings) give isotopic links.

Here is my thinking so far:

If edges are the curves between intersections and nodes are intersections, the associated graph seems to have two kinds of data:

1. The adjacency data
2. Over-under data at each node (specifying which two incoming edges pass over the other two)

These two sorts of data are easy to translate into graph-theoretic language.  The second kind actually has nothing to do with the graph structure and doesn't constrain the graph at all; one can make over-under assignments however one wants and still get a link diagram.  But there also seems to be some strange third constraint that captures the "transversality" of the intersections, and I'm not sure how that would be described combinatorially.

Comment: There are a number of combinatorial systems for encoding link diagrams. Gauss codes and Dowker-Thistlethwaite notation are pretty common.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Thanks, I'll have a look at those.